# Blank Page Footer leaves space in Crystal Report

Tags: footer, formula, crystal-reports-2008, suppress

Problem:

I have a multiple page footers which are suppressed conditionally, but even after hiding the page footer, it leaves space and whole formatting is vague now in my Crystal Report.

Is there any way to remove extra blank space from Report when Page Footer is hidden?
I have tried using "**Suppress Blank Section**" option, but then also no help.

Crystal Report version - 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a better answer. I'd need more details of the footer contents & conditions for suppression. That said, I would try the following:

1. Set the footer contents to also be conditionally hidden/suppressed with the same logic used in the footer section itself.
2. If that doesn't solve your problem, try debugging by removing all footer contents. If "suppress if blank" functions correctly after this, then your problem is that one of the items in the footer is not actually blank.
3. If the footer still isn't suppressed, try going into design mode, zoom wayyyy out, and see if there might be something outside of the visible page template in the footer section that is causing the section to not be blank... if page dimensions or settings were changed at some point, or you placed a lot of items in the report at the same time, CR will sometimes cause items to be outside of the dimensions of the page template, but still within the section.

Those steps aside, there's not much we do without specific details. Try giving an example of the desired behavior, and desired conditions to trigger that behavior, and we can advise further.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to have varying footers and display only a single one based on the conditional suppressions, then what you want is the "Reserve Minimum Page Footer".

To find this option, open the Section Expert and select "Page Footer" (the parent to Page Footer a,b,c etc.) Under the 'Common' tab you should find the "Reserve Minimum Page Footer" option.

What this does, is instead of reserving space equal to the sum height of all your footers, it reserves space equal to the height of your biggest footer. Which isn't perfect, but it is better. (And if all your footers are about the same height, it is perfect. If you had varying sizes, you will still have some blank space when displaying a short footer, and that blank space will be BELOW the footer, so I would adjust all footer sections to be the same size, and shift the content to the bottom of the section.)

The problem with this though, and this is the problem I am having and am yet to solve, is when you want to display multiple footers, it will still only use the space that is reserved, which is the height of the single largest footer, anything else that is displayed overflows below the page.

I am yet to find a solution that will dynamically adjust the height of the footer based on what is displayed in the footer.

Comment: Well, there is no such option "Reserve minimum Page Footer:" and please read question carefully, I am asking about Report Footer, not page footer.